# How to Click Asp.net Gridview Paging through C# web Browser?

Tags: c#

I Have Some data in table format with paging.
how can I access all the paging data from the web browser without visiting the web page using c# web browser.

Now I am able to access only 1st page data.

This is my Code.

```
DataTable mDt = new DataTable();
int startPosotion = table.InnerHtml.IndexOf("<tbody>"); // Start <tbody> from where Actual Data Exist
int endPosotion = table.InnerHtml.IndexOf("</tbody>"); // End </tbody> where Data Finish
string data = table.InnerHtml.Substring(startPosotion, (endPosotion - startPosotion) + count);
data = data.Replace("<br>", "<br></br>");

XmlTextReader xml = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(data));
int i = 0; // DataTable Columns
List<string> c = new List<string>();

while (xml.Read())
{
    switch (xml.NodeType)
    {
       case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
            c.Add(xml.Value);
            i++;
            break;
    }

    if (i == 9)
    {
        var rows = mDt.Select("TransactionId='" + c[0] + "'");
        if (rows == null || rows.Count() == 0)
        {
            var z = c[3].ToString().Trim() + " " + c[4].ToString().Trim() + " " + c[5].ToString().Trim();
            mDt.Rows.Add(c[0].ToString().Trim(), c[1].ToString().Trim(), c[2].ToString().Trim(), z, c[6].ToString().Trim(), c[7].ToString().Trim(), c[8].ToString().Trim());
        }

        i = 0;
        c = new List<string>();
    }
}
dgvTariff.DataSource = mDt;
dgvTariff.Refresh();
```

Plz Give me any solution, how to get all paging data in C# web browser through programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

1-  Create a windows application and use `System.Web.Form.WebBrowser` control in the windows form.

2-  Set the default page url using `Navigate` methods and pass your first page URL like `webBrowser.Navigate(url)`

3-  Handel the `DocumentCompleted` event and capture the data. Once the data is captured for the current page from the `webBrowser.Document`. Using webBrowser.Document object find the link of the next page link from the document using `

```
HtmlElement submit = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("lnkNext");`
//Invoke the click
submit.InvokeMember("click");
```

This will do the post back and will load the next page and your `DocumentCompleted` event will again get invoked.

Repeat step 3 until you reach to the last page.